# Login no facebook com python

Tags: python, python-3.x, http

Eu gostaria, por motivo didático, de fazer login no facebook com um script de python. Tentei com a lib [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)

```
import requests

s = requests.Session()
post_url = 'https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1&lwv=110'

headers = {"User-agent" : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1'}
login_data = {'email': 'USERNAME', 'pass': 'PASSWORD'}
pag_formulario = s.post(formulario_url, headers=headers, data=login_data)
```

Mas não parece estar a funcionar. Alguém já tenha feito isso?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Com requests (só) é dificil fazer login no facebook, até porque eles devem apostar em javascript para gerar dados adicionais para segurança, e seria muito complicado rastrear tudo o que acontece. Para além disso deve enviar (metodo post) todos os valores do formulário. Sei isso porque também já tentei e não resultou só com requests.

Contudo tem outros modulos que podem ajudar.

Para python >= 2.4 e < 3 (python 2.x), pode usar [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/):

```
import mechanize

url = 'https://m.facebook.com'
loggedin_title = 'Facebook' # isto vai servir para confirmarmos que estamos loggedin, vendo o titulo da pagina para onde fomos redirecionados 
username = 'USERNAME'
password = 'PASSWORD'

browser = mechanize.Browser()
browser.set_handle_robots(False)
browser.addheaders = [('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.0.6)')]

browser.open(url)
browser.select_form(nr=0)
browser.form["email"] = username
browser.form["pass"] = password
browser.submit()

if browser.title() == loggedin_title:
    print '[+] SUCCESS'
    print 'Username: {}\nPassword: {}'.format(username, password)
else:
    print '[-] LOGIN FAILED'
```

Para python >= 3, pode [instalar](http://robobrowser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) o [robobrowser](http://robobrowser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), este também faz uso do modulo requests:

```
import robobrowser
import re

url = 'https://m.facebook.com'
loggedin_title = 'Facebook' # isto vai servir para confirmarmos que estamos loggedin, vendo o titulo da pagina para onde fomos redirecionados 

browser = robobrowser.RoboBrowser(history=True, parser='html.parser')
browser.open(url)

form = browser.get_form(id='login_form')
form['email'].value = 'USERNAME'
form['pass'].value = 'PASSWORD'
browser.submit_form(form, submit=form['login'])

redirect_title = re.compile('<title>(.*?)</title>').search(str(browser.parsed)).group(1)

if(redirect_title == loggedin_title):
    print('[+] SUCCESS')
    print('Username: {}\nPassword: {}'.format(form['email'].value, form['pass'].value))
else:
    print('[-] LOGIN FAILED')
```

Nesta ultima não é preciso definir headers, mas pode. Os headers deste por default são suficientes e válidos para o facebook.

Nota que este código só é estável até o facebook mudar a mecânica de login, caso isso aconteça isto terá de ser adaptado

[Aqui](http://facebook-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) tem a alternativa 'oficial' oferecida pelo próprio facebook.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta @Miguel ajudou-me muito!

Comment: De nada @Allan, ainda bem

Comment: A resposta está corretíssima. Para complementar: sites que dependem muito de conteúdo dinâmico, como twitter e facebook, em geral não se prestam bem a serem acessados automaticamente simulando um navegador - como nesse caso. Isso por que todas as págians vão depender de código javascript para ter seu conteúdo apresentado.

Esses portais em geral oferecem uma API para acesso automático, e para ter acesso que permita buscas, postagens, etc... o melhor é usar a API. 
Confira: 
http://facebook-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html https://pypi.python.org/pypi/facebook-sdk

Comment: Obgado @jsbueno, eu só não coloquei essa alternativa pois não me pareceu que o AP quisesse isso. Já editei acrescentando essa opção. Obrigado

Comment: Sim - quando é assim, eu costumo dar a resposta direta, e escrever a orientação para a "forma correta em geral" ao final. (que foi o que eu fiz no comentário acima :-)  ). As vezes quando o que o AP está indo por um caminho muito errado, já inidco a forma correta de cara.

Comment: Muito Obgado @jsbueno . Aqui creio que não havia errado nem certo, era só para que o AP, "por motivo didático", conseguisse fazer 'login' no facebook via um script de python

Comment: Sim - mesmo que o AP saiba exatamente o que está perguntando, é legl ter em mente que a pergunta e resposta serão acessadas por outras pessoas procurando por coisas semelhantes. E em geral elas vão querer fazer do jeito mais direto e certo. Eu tenho uma resposta clássica no S.O. em inglês que para responder a pergunta precisa de várias convoluções, mas o jeito "simples" é o que 99% das pessoas querem, e está ao final da resposta: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15247075/how-can-i-dynamically-create-derived-classes-from-a-base-class/15247892#15247892