# Com fazer posts no Facebook com Python?

Tags: python, facebook

```
import facebook

token = 'meu token'



graph = facebook.GraphAPI(token)
graph.put_object("me", "feed", message="Hello, World!")
```

Amigos,

Estou utilizando Ubuntu e Python 2.7 e 3.5.2

O seguinte erro ocorre:

"graph = facebook.GraphAPI(ACCESS_TOKEN)
AttributeError: module 'facebook' has no attribute 'GraphAPI"

Já pesquisei em aqui mesmo no Stack Overflow mas nenhuma resposta resolveu meu problema.

Instalei o Facebook-SDK daqui:

http://facebook-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Tente baixar um código já pronto e construir seu aplicativo à partir dele.

Comment: import facebook -> no modo interativo nao da erros

Comment: from facebook import GraphAPI -> tambem nao ocorre erros

Comment: @CypherPotato, alguma sugestao de codigo?

Comment: Tente sobrecarregar a função ```GraphAPI```: ```facebook.GraphAPI(access_token='your_token', version='2.2')```

Comment: @CypherPotato, eu fiz mas o erro foi o mesmo!

Comment: Ed, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/142790/login-no-facebook-com-python . Não é bem como fazer posts mas é relacionado. No entanto usar sdk é o indicado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se estiver usando Ubuntu ou Debian, execute estes comandos para voltar a funcionar.

```
sudo pip uninstall facebook
sudo pip uninstall facebook-sdk
sudo pip install facebook-sdk
```

Para outros sistemas operacionais, apenas remova o `facebook` e `facebook-sdk` e instale apenas o `facebook-sdk`

Então execute o programa. Observe que o módulo `facebook` é obsoleto e seu substituto é o `facebook-sdk`.

[Fonte da resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19893523/python-facebook-sdk-module-object-has-no-attribute-graphapi)

.

Comment: sudo pip uninstall facebook -> Cannot uninstall requirement facebook, not installed

Comment: Tudo que eu queria era conseguir um script python para postar no facebook... que erro chato!