# Enviando POST com Python através curl

Tags: python, python-3.x, formulário, post, libcurl

Quero transformar o formulário (que está funcionando) em um curl para rodar no backend

```
<form action="https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/login?ssrc=head&returnurl=https%3a%2f%2fpt.stackoverflow.com%2f" method="post">

        <input type="text" name="email"></input>
        <input type="password" name="password"></input>

        <input type="submit" value="enviar"></input>
    </form>
```

Tentativa de curl em python:

```
import urllib 
url = 'https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/login?ssrc=head&returnurl=https%3a%2f%2fpt.stackoverflow.com%2f'
values = {'email': 'l472402@mvrht.com', 'password' : '$teste123','submit': 'SUBMIT'}
dados = urllib.urlencode(values)
html = urllib.urlopen(url,dados).read()
print (html)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Quero transformar o formulário em um curl para rodar no backend"?!

Tens alguns conceitos para apurar, e estamos aqui para te ajudar a conseguir isso.

O que estás a fazer não é uso do curl, é uso de uma biblioteca ([urllib](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/urllib.html)) de python que em muitos aspetos é semelhante e serve para as mesmas coisas.

O que estás a tentar fazer, login no stackoverflow, duvido que resulte assim, deve haver processos de segurança para evitar isso, por exemplo, carregamento por javascript de payloads a enviar para o servidor no processo de login.

Supondo que resultaria, a maneira correta seria:

```
import urllib, urllib.parse, urllib.request
url = 'https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/login?ssrc=head&returnurl=https%3a%2f%2fpt.stackoverflow.com%2f'
values = {'email': 'l472402@mvrht.com', 'password' : '$teste123','submit': 'SUBMIT'}
dados = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url, dados.encode()).read().decode() # decode de bytes para string
print(html)
```

Teste de um request POST:

```
import urllib, urllib.parse, urllib.request
url = 'http://httpbin.org/post'
values = {'email': 'l472402@mvrht.com', 'password' : '$teste123','submit': 'SUBMIT'}
dados = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url, dados.encode()).read().decode() # decode de bytes para string
print(html)
```

A ver também:

[Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)
[Outras maneiras de login](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/142790/login-no-facebook-com-python)

Comment: Agradeço!
Qual das 2 formas é melhor? 

#modo1
r = requests.post(url, data=valor)
print(r.text)
"""
#modo2
dados = urllib.parse.urlencode(valor)
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url, dados.encode()).read().decode()
print (html)

Comment: @DaniloAlbergardi pessoalmente prefiro usar requests por conhecer melhor e para mim ser mais simples. Mas alcanças o mesmo com urlib, é uma questão de gosto

Comment: @DaniloAlbergardi acerca desta tua questão em comentário: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018026/what-are-the-differences-between-the-urllib-urllib2-and-requests-module

Comment: ok, muito obrigado!