# Aplicação para login em outro site (Facebook), erro "InvalidSubmitError"

Tags: python, xml, login, parser, library

Meu código é esse:

```
import robobrowser
import re

url = 'https://m.facebook.com'
loggedin_title = 'Facebook' # isto vai servir para confirmarmos que estamos loggedin, vendo o titulo da pagina para onde fomos redirecionados 

browser = robobrowser.RoboBrowser(history=True)
browser.open(url)

form = browser.get_form(id='login_form')
form['email'].value = 'USERNAME'
form['pass'].value = 'PASSWORD'
browser.submit_form(form)

redirect_title = re.compile('<title>(.*?)</title>').search(str(browser.parsed)).group(1)

if(redirect_title == loggedin_title):
    print('[+] SUCCESS')
    print('Username: {}\nPassword: {}'.format(form['email'].value, form['pass'].value))
else:
    print('[-] LOGIN FAILED')
```

Mas obtenho este erro e não consigo solucioná-lo:

> ```
> Warning (from warnings module):
>   File "C:\Users\EDUARDO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 181
>     markup_type=markup_type))
> UserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified, so I'm using the best available HTML parser for this system ("lxml"). This usually isn't a problem, but if you run this code on another system, or in a different virtual environment, it may use a different parser and behave differently.
>
> The code that caused this warning is on line 1 of the file <string>. To get rid of this warning, change code that looks like this:
>
>  BeautifulSoup(YOUR_MARKUP})
>
> to this:
>
>  BeautifulSoup(YOUR_MARKUP, "lxml")
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users\ED\Documents\Python\Python\Python\LOGIN\login.py", line 13, in <module>
>     browser.submit_form(form)
>   File "C:\Users\ED\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\robobrowser\browser.py", line 339, in submit_form
>     payload = form.serialize(submit=submit)
>   File "C:\Users\ED\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\robobrowser\forms\form.py", line 226, in serialize
>     include_fields = prepare_fields(self.fields, self.submit_fields, submit)
>   File "C:\Users\ED\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\robobrowser\forms\form.py", line 154, in prepare_fields
>     raise exceptions.InvalidSubmitError()
> robobrowser.exceptions.InvalidSubmitError
> ```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Login no facebook com python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/142790/login-no-facebook-com-python)

Comment: @prmottajr, eu respondi a essa, mas de facto precisava de ser atualizada, e o parser devia ser passado neste caso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloca o parametro `submit` com o botão correspondente:

```
...
browser.submit_form(form, submit=form['login'])
...
```

Ficando assim:

```
import robobrowser
import re

url = 'https://m.facebook.com'
loggedin_title = 'Facebook' # isto vai servir para confirmarmos que estamos loggedin, vendo o titulo da pagina para onde fomos redirecionados 

browser = robobrowser.RoboBrowser(history=True, parser='html.parser')
browser.open(url)

form = browser.get_form(id='login_form')
form['email'].value = 'USERNAME'
form['pass'].value = 'PASSWORD'
browser.submit_form(form, submit=form['login']) # <-- acresentar aqui

redirect_title = re.compile('<title>(.*?)</title>').search(str(browser.parsed)).group(1)

if(redirect_title == loggedin_title):
    print('[+] SUCCESS')
    print('Username: {}\nPassword: {}'.format(form['email'].value, form['pass'].value))
else:
    print('[-] LOGIN FAILED')
```

[DOCS](https://robobrowser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: Cheguei a instalar uma versão anterior do Python pra tentar resolver, mas não adiantou. Com sua ajuda melhorou, mas ainda há um erro a ser resolvido. Ele completa a leitura do código, mas ainda traz o erro relacionado ao BeautifulSoup:

Comment: @Scienceandsociety Mas fizeste o login? Isso é só um warning

Comment: @Scienceandsociety, acho que o próprio robobrowser é que está a importar mal o beautifulsoup. faz update a esse pacote ou desintala e instala outravez

Comment: Sim, o login foi feito. Esse erro ainda incomoda. Já fiz o upgrade do pacote, mas não funciona. No próprio erro, ele diz pra trocar BeautifulSoup(YOUR_MARKUP}) por BeautifulSoup(YOUR_MARKUP, "html.parser") no arquivo "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", o problema é que na linha indicada não tem isso "BeautifulSoup(YOUR_MARKUP})"

Comment: Editei a resposta @Scienceandsociety, com uma possível solução: `robobrowser.RoboBrowser(history=True, parser='html.parser')`

Comment: Valeu Miguel! Funcionou perfeitamente! Pensei que essa edição tivesse que ser feita no arquivo da biblioteca. Obrigado!

Comment: @Scienceandsociety de nada, eu também não sabia, tive de ir ver os docs